# Is it incorrect to say I'm 20 years old next month?

Tags: present-simple, future-time, future-constructions

Is it incorrect to say

> I'm 20 years old next month.

I'm learning through an English app. It says that the sentence above is incorrect and the correct answer is

> I shall be 20 years old next month.

There were 4 choices to this question in the app:

> I (am/shall/shall be/will) 20 years old next month.

I thought present simple is appropriate there since this tense can be used to describe the future.

Comment: You can use future or present. 'Shall' (future) is correct, although rather formal (at least in British usage), 'will' is less formal, and the present (e.g. 'am') is also correct. That app sounds very limited and not very good.

Comment: ''I shall be 20 years old next month'' is correct but sounds very ''posh'' and formal.  ''I'm 20 years old next month'' is correct as far as I know and sounds much more natural in conversation.

Comment: Other grammatically correct sentences that could be used in different instances, just for fun: "I was going to be 20 next month", "I would have been 20 next month", and perhaps even (not 100% sure about this one) "I was going to have been 20 next month" - all mean more or less the opposite of the OP's sentence

Comment: The present tense can be used to describe the future, but such doesn't always sound idiomatic. If you instead use "will" to indicate the future tense, you will almost never sound incorrect.

Comment: "I shall be 20 years old next month" sounds to me like there's another half missing : ", provided I don't die before". Could this be an interpretation?

Comment: As a note, my preference would be to use "will" in a sentence like that but the options include "shall be" and just "will".  Without the "be" the sentence would be "I will 20 years old next month" which is plain wrong.

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss ' just for fun: "I was going to be 20 next month"' - I think someone would only say that if they know they are going to die before their forthcoming birthday, which I would hardly describe as "fun", or maybe if they have just discovered that their birth certificate had the wrong date on it.

Comment: "shall" is also a flatly incorrect answer. Dump that app

Comment: @gotube the suggested answer is 'shall be'.  'Shall' on its own is just an option.

Comment: Half a century ago, *I **shall** be back tonight* was [actually more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+shall+be+back+tonight%2CI+will+be+back+tonight&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) than *I **will** be back tonight*. But today you'd very rarely come across "shall" used in such contexts. I'm sure my linked NGram *overstates* how often people say "shall". Superficially it looks like about 1 in 5 usages are "shall" rather than "will", but in reality I'm sure it's nowhere even 1 in 10 in speech. NGrams is *written* instances (plus *copied* older texts).

Comment: Middle class south of England raised in the 70s: "I shall be" would be the most natural here. To the American who flatly deny it, what do you make of Bob Dylan's "I shall be released" song?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You certainly can use the present tense (I am, he is, we are, etc) about a scheduled event, and many people do so when discussing a forthcoming birthday. I am sixty tomorrow, I am fifty in March, I am fifty in two years, I am forty in four weeks,  I am 35 in a couple of months.  You can also say (e.g.) 'I will be 26 in a few weeks', and British users may well use 'shall', which is more formal.

> We use the present simple for something scheduled:
>
> We have a lesson next Monday.
> The train arrives at 6.30 in the morning.
> The holidays start next week.
> **It's my birthday tomorrow**.

[Talking about the future (British Council)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future)

> Wrexham MP Ian Lucas will stand down at next election - 11 Oct 2019 —
> "I am 60 next year. I have been an MP since I was 40. I think the time
> is right for me to choose to follow a different path in the years to
> come" (BBC)
>
> Ex-soldier from Hornchurch in diving world record bid: 14 Feb 2016 —
> He said: “I am 50 next year and so this is my last chance to get the
> record. I want to stay underwater for five days." Hornchurch Recorder
> (Essex newspaper).

On the the more formal side, from the *Letters of CH Spurgeon* (1834 - 1892), a British preacher and religious writer:

> May the everlasting arms be underneath you! I breathe for you a
> loving, tender prayer,—" Lord, comfort Thy dear servant, and when he
> departs, may it be across a dried-up river into the land of living
> fountains!" **I am fifty next Thursday**, and you are near your Jubilee.
> In this we are alike; but Jesus is the highest joy. Into the Father's
> hands I commit you, "until the day break, and the shadows flee away."
> Your loving brother, C. H. SPURGEON.

[image]

Comment: To add, "shall" here is exceedingly formal to the point of being incorrect in modern usage, at least in my (American) opinion. If OP's app says "shall" is the correct answer I would hesitate to trust it on anything else.

Comment: @randomhead - to me (I shall be 70 next April), UK (English), middle class, using 'shall' is a little old-fashioned and rather formal but not howlingly archaic and definitely not 'wrong' or 'incorrect'. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/shall) quoting _English Grammar Today_ says 'Shall is only used for future time reference with I and we, and is more formal than will'. _In July I shall be 50_ (The Times, 2018), _in another six months, I shall be 50, and, therefore, become entitled to benefit_ (Hansard - UK Parliamament record, 1964)

Comment: I think the formality of “shall” might be a difference between BrE and AmE. In the USA, I almost never hear “shall” used in any context other than legal - certainly not in everyday spoken English. If someone said “I shan’t be pleased” to me, I’d ask them what that quote is from, because I’d never think that’s just someone talking.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129420/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-harvey-is-it-incorrect-to-say-im-20-years-old-n).

Comment: As a speaker of AmE who has read a **lot** of BrE I find "I am 60 tomorrow" odd and not at all idiomatic, and "I am 60 in three months": flatly wrong. I accept that this usage occurs in some parts of the UK, but would still advise learners to avoid it. "I will be 60 tomorrow": is correct in all forms of English.

Answer (score 18):

Want to add to the accepted answer: using the present tense to speak about future events is common, but to my intuitive understanding as a native US speaker is incorrect... except that it's understood to be a shortening of saying "I am/I'm *going to be* 20 years old next month."

Saying "I will/I'll be 20 years old next month" is overwhelmingly the most correct/normal way to say it in my experience, but saying "I'm 20 years old next month" is perfectly acceptable, because it's understood to imply the absent "*going to be*".

Resultingly, it'd seem wrong written down in any context besides the most informal and conversational (personal communication/blog posts/anything emulating face-to-face conversation). In professional communication, essays, or in a book (unless it's in dialogue between characters), use of the present tense would be interpreted as either agrammatical or out-of-place due to its informality.

Comment: +1 - Native AmE speaker here, and "I'm 20 years old next month" (without the implied "going to be") sounds incorrect enough for me to ask the speaker to clarify/repeat themselves, and might make me question their fluency.

Comment: @A N: Same here.  I think almost anyone would say either "I will be..." (hardly anyone uses shall), or "I'm going to be...".

Comment: -1: English doesn't have a future tense. There are numerous constructions which talk about the future solely using a present tense construction, such as "I'm visiting my aunt tomorrow." (compare to: "I'm visiting my aunt right now."). You cannot add a "going to" to that sentence without recasting it altogether. There is simply no grammatical requirement to add any sort of marker explicitly indicating the future, because the future is not grammaticalized in English (unlike the past). Insisting otherwise is a hypercorrection.

Comment: @Kevin English only doesn't have a future tense if you use a very technical definition of the word "tense" which requires that the word be altered. It very much does have standard constructions that indicate that an action takes place in the future, or that a state will become true in the future. Using the construction "I'm 20 next month" does not use these standard markers. It is something that may occur in colloquial English, but is generally regarded as non-standard grammar, at least, in American English.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129421/discussion-on-answer-by-neph-is-it-incorrect-to-say-im-20-years-old-next-month).

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of how colloquial speech leaves out or contracts redundant words.

Your third quote shows "I am 20..." as acceptable, and "I'm 20..." is merely the shortened (spoken or even lazy) way of saying the same.

Upshot - your app isn't quite smart enough to know they're the same.

Comment: I don't think it's even colloquial speech, except perhaps in some dialects.

Comment: @jamesqf perhaps "spoken shortcuts" rather than colloquial.  Notice your own comment line contains two abbreviations    "I do not think it is even colloquial speech"

Comment: Perhaps we're thinking of different things?  I didn't mean the contractions, I meant the idea of using present tense for a future state, saying "I'm 20 next month", rather than "I'll be 20 next month".  Which itself contracts "I will" (or shall for the pedantic) and "20 years old".

Comment: You missed the point, the app is not saying `I am` is correct it's just a multiple choice answer and one of the choice was `I am` which the OP chose and the app told him it was wrong, he is the one who shortened it in his question

Comment: @Tofandel well... that's confusing.  Good spotting.

Comment: @Tofandel - it's just that whoever created the app was ignorant about British English, or decided it didn't count.

Comment: It could very well be that if the OP had written "am" that the app would have accepted the answer. Do we know? Many a time an online checker will mark a correct answer wrong because of an extra character space, a missing full stop (period) at the end, a contraction, or because a word was spelt (spelled) using the BrEng convention.

Answer (score 0):

> I am 20 years old next month

I have a feeling that the aforementioned construction derives from a very formal way to express a future event that is considered inevitable or expected, e.g:

> Soon **I am to be** 20 years old.
> “**We are to be** married in the month of June”

The formula **be to + infinitive**  can be replaced by **am/is/are going to + infinitive**

Google books revealed the following quotations

1. **To-morrow I am to be arraigned as a culprit**; my friends may leave me, my counsel may desert my cause as hopeless, and the world may point at me as a recreant to virtue…
   [*To love and To Be Loved*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/To_love_and_to_be_loved_by_the_author_of/l64BAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I+am+to+be%22&pg=PA196&printsec=frontcover) 1855
2. “I am very intimate, especially with Matilda: **I am to be one of her bridesmaids**. You know, of course, that the wedding-day is fixed for to-morrow?” 1853
3. “**Tomorrow is to be one of our anniversaries,** you know,” she replied; “twenty-four years ago – to-morrow — was to have been to me what to-day is to Linnet. I wonder if I *were* [sic] as light hearted as Linnet.”
4. “…for science is inexhaustible; every day opens a glimpse of some fact that **tomorrow is to see** ascertained.” *Significance of the Alphabet* By Charles Kraitsir, 1846

Today that line might be written as “that tomorrow sees ascertained” or “that tomorrow will see ascertained.”

Answer (score -1):

**The TL;DR version:**

**"I am 20 years old next month" is incorrect because in that sentence "20 years old" is an adjective which describes you. 
Remember that [the verb 'to be' plus an adjective is used to talk about the present](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/to-be-adjective/).**

**"It is my 20th birthday next month" is correct because the object of the sentence is the birthday, and is [a scheduled event in the future](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future).**

Original answer follows:

---

> I'm 20 years old next month.

Is understandable but grammatically incorrect, although frequently used colloquially.

---

*Begin edit*

As an aside. @Muzer comments that "It's not grammatically incorrect. -1.".

It is incorrect in that form, because if you want to use "I am" to speak about the future then it should be combined with a verb ending in "-ing". Here's how you can use "I am" correctly:

> I am going to be 20 next month.

> I'm turning 20 next month.

If you're talking about the birthday, as a scheduled event, then you can use the present tense like this:

> It is my 20th birthday next month.

For more, see https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future

*End edit*

---

> I'll be 20 years old next month.

Is grammatically correct, but in my opinion:

> **I'll turn 20 next month.**

Is the best way of saying what you want to say.

If you're currently 20 then it's not incorrect to say you'll be 20 next month, too; but to say that you will *turn* 20 suggests that your 20th birthday is next month.

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect. -1.

Comment: @Muzer Using the present tense "I am" without a verb ending in -ing to talk about the future is ungrammatical. You can say "It's my 20th birthday next month", you can say "I'm going to be 20 next month", you can say "I'm turning 20 next month", but "I'm 20 next month" is not correct. I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Muzer Also, being grammatically incorrect doesn't mean that it's not frequently used in day-to-day speech by many people, and therefore not strictly incorrect to say "I am 20 years old next month" :-)

Comment: (and only after editing do I notice that I've used the exact same example and reference as the accepted answer - that wasn't intentional)

Comment: "Tonight we dine in hell", "eat, drink and be merry for tomorrow we die", etc. - I don't think there's anything ungrammatical here. Indeed look at point 1 in the page you linked yourself. If something is scheduled there's no need for "-ing" or an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @Muzer I think that "tonight we dine" and "tomorrow we die" are slightly different cases. If rephrased to use "I am" (or "we are") you would say "tonight we are dining" or "tomorrow we are dying", _or_ "tonight we will dine" or "tomorrow we will die". If I try and construct a sentence using "we are" and the present tense of the verb it's not right: eg. "tonight we are dine"/"tomorrow we are dead"

Comment: "Tomorrow we are dead" sounds fine to me. Just like "I'm 20 tomorrow".

Comment: @Muzer it might sound fine, and be used colloquially, but it's not grammatically correct :-D

Comment: You say _I **am** 20 years old next month_ is grammatically incorrect, then say that _It **is** my 20th birthday next month_ is fine? Show some consistency! _I **will be** 20 years old next month_ & _It **will be** my 20th birthday next month_ Either they're both good using the simple present conjugation of _to be_, or both bad. To me, they're both fine.

Comment: @CJDennis The difference between the two is whether there's an object of the verb "to be" in the sentence. With "it's my birthday next month" the object of the verb "to be" is the birthday. With "I'm 20 next month" there's no object, only an adjective "20". When using the construction <verb "to be"> + <adjective>, we're talking about the present. When using <verb "to be"> + <infinitive>, we're talking about the future.

Comment: @CJDennis I've edited the answer to demonstrate the difference as simply as possible

Comment: Actually, I disagree. _20_ is ellipsed from _20 years old_, which can certainly be an object. Simple Present tense + time marker = tense of time marker. "I am better as of yesterday." "I feel good now." "I am running a marathon tomorrow."

Comment: @CJDennis "20 years old" is an adjective, not a noun ("a 20-year-old" would be a noun). See the question [Difference between "two years old and two-year-old"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/difference-between-two-years-old-and-two-year-old) for the difference. (edit, [here's an external link](https://www.englishforums.com/blog/years-old-or-years-old/) as well - not all of the answers are exactly reliable, as this question and answers demonstrate)

Comment: You state categorically "'I am 20 years old next month' is incorrect". Other native English speakers disagree with you, saying it sounds fine to them, and they'd use it themselves. The most you can say is "'I am 20 years old next month' sounds wrong to me", but then your answer is no better than an opinion. Remember, grammar is descriptive, not prescriptive. The fact that enough other native English speakers say it's fine is what makes it fine. I note you've got the same number of downvotes as the top two answers without attracting anywhere near the same number of upvotes.

Comment: @CJDennis you say: 'You state categorically "'I am 20 years old next month' is incorrect"' - no I don't, I stated that it's **grammatically** incorrect, and I noted it's frequently used colloquially. I then refer to rules of grammar to explain _why_ it's **grammatically** incorrect.  You say ' The most you can say is "'I am 20 years old next month' sounds wrong to me"' - no I didn't, nowhere have I said that it sounds wrong to me. I'm not sure why you're inventing quotes. The top answers attracted many upvotes due to the question being on HNQ. My answer was posted a day after the accepted one.

Comment: @CJDennis And the accepted answer isn't a very good answer: it refers to a grammar rule which is correct but doesn't apply to the example in the question (birthday = scheduled event, but age = adjective), and then uses two examples of spoken (colloquial) English and one example of a 19th century letter, but doesn't attempt to inform the OP _why_ their app told them they were wrong. Obviously the OP is only concerned with being told they were right, but if they try and apply this 'rule' of "i am"+<adjective> to refer to the future when talking about anything else then it won't work.

Comment: So far, 35 people disagree with you that the accepted answer isn't good. I haven't voted on this question or any of the answers (either up or down), so none of those include me. I will repeat what I said before. **Remember, grammar is descriptive, not prescriptive. The fact that enough other native English speakers say it's fine is what makes it fine.**

Comment: I have a feeling that it derives from a very formal way to express a future event that is inevitable, e.g:"I am/ We are to be married in the month of June"

Comment: [the difference between I'm to be and I will be](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141592/the-difference-between-im-to-be-and-i-will-be)

Comment: @CJDennis "Remember, grammar is descriptive, not prescriptive" - it's neither one nor the other. Descriptive and prescriptive are two sides of the same coin. See [linguistic description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) and [linguistic prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription). I think that here on [ell.se] prescriptive rules are more helpful to those learning the language, whereas descriptive is more useful on [english.se] and [linguistics.se] to people studying language, who already know the rules and want to learn how and when to break them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's interesting. I thought that the expression "I am to be" turned into "I am going to be" in modern usage. This would be an example where, instead of adding "going", the "to be" was dropped completely, turning "I am to be 20 next month" into "I am 20 next month". I wonder if there are any other instances of this happening? I can't think of any off the top of my head.